# BizTalk flatfile schema tags not at start of line

Tags: biztalk

I am having trouble understanding how to create a schema for the following type of flatfiles due to the fact that the tag identifier is not on the second field.

I removed some extra data from the below example, but my problem is pretty much that the tag identifier (HDR/ODR and END) is preceded by an incremental number.

```
000001  HDR 0000031001  1DP 
000002  ORD 0000031001  0001
000003  ORD 0000031001  0001
000004  ORD 0000031001  0001
000005  ORD 0000031001  0001
000006  END
```

Solutions I have seen on google seem to be debatching the lines based on the first element assuming it is the same for all fields but that doesn't work in this case.

Is there a way to set up the tag as the second element?

The file is tab separated.

Comment: Have you tried using the offset? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560980.aspx

Comment: @PieterVandenheede Except that seems to be for a positional record rather than a delimited one.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf you are quite right. I should pay more attention to pages I post here.

Answer (score 3):

If there are only those 3 tags, and the HDR and END only occur once, just create a schema where you have a schema where you have three records, 1 for the HDR, 1 for the ORD which can occur multiple times, and one for the END.
You also have to alter the Lookahead depth from the default 3 to 0 (infinite).

For example the following schema would parse that correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.46345356" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.46345356" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="0" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="HDR">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x9" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Line" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Tag" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Data1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Data2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ORD">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x9" child_order="infix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Line" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Tag" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Data1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Data2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="END">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0x9" child_order="infix" sequence_number="3" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Line" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Tag" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Resulting in

```
<Root xmlns="http://Scratch.46345356">
    <HDR xmlns="">
        <Line>000001</Line>
        <Tag>HDR</Tag>
        <Data1>0000031001</Data1>
        <Data2>1DP</Data2>
    </HDR>
    <ORD xmlns="">
        <Line>000002</Line>
        <Tag>ORD</Tag>
        <Data1>0000031001</Data1>
        <Data2>0001</Data2>
    </ORD>
    <ORD xmlns="">
        <Line>000003</Line>
        <Tag>ORD</Tag>
        <Data1>0000031001</Data1>
        <Data2>0001</Data2>
    </ORD>
    <ORD xmlns="">
        <Line>000004</Line>
        <Tag>ORD</Tag>
        <Data1>0000031001</Data1>
        <Data2>0001</Data2>
    </ORD>
    <ORD xmlns="">
        <Line>000005</Line>
        <Tag>ORD</Tag>
        <Data1>0000031001</Data1>
        <Data2>0001</Data2>
    </ORD>
    <END xmlns="">
        <Line>000006</Line>
        <Tag>END</Tag>
    </END>
</Root>
```

Comment: have been testing this and it works but you set up a max occurs 4 in the schema. this means if there is 5 lines it stops working. making the maxOccurs unbounded makes it so the schema doesn't know when to stop and keeps trying to add lines to "ORD" until the end where it errors expecting an '\t'. Would it be possible to make this work with a variable amount of ORDs (and keeping HDR and ENDs to 1 each)

Comment: @Andy That is how mine is, the HRD and END are occur 1, and the ORD unbounded, so their can be any number of ORD lines. So you must have some other issue.  If so, please create a new question with a sample file and a schema that demonstrates the issue

Comment: i'm having trouble wether to accept this as the answer as not, i failed to solve the issue with your schema but came very close. In the end, i ran low on time and fixed it by doing a horrible hack with 2 interfaces so i could make the first column be the last and use a tag identifier. Since the customer changed the requirement to actually have recurring tags, this answer wouldn't help me on the new request anymore either.  I could delete the question but the answer did help me so i am not sure on that either.

Comment: @Andy Entirely up to you if you want to accept it or not.  Note: I did update it after you pointed out that it was not handling the re-occurrence properly in the other question

Answer (score 1):

Use Tag Identifier and Tag Offset you achieve your objective:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://BizTalkMassCopy.FlatFileSchema6" targetNamespace="http://BizTalkMassCopy.FlatFileSchema6" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Header">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="positional" tag_name="HDR" tag_offset="8" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Count" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="8" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="TagId" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="17" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="4" maxOccurs="4" name="Ord">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="positional" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="ORD" tag_offset="8" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Count" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="8" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="TagId" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="17" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="End">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="positional" sequence_number="3" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" tag_name="END" tag_offset="8" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Count" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="8" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="TagId" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" pos_offset="0" pos_length="3" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The result is this:

```
<Root xmlns="http://BizTalkMassCopy.FlatFileSchema6">
  <Header xmlns="">
    <Count>000001</Count>
    <TagId>HDR</TagId>
    <Item> 0000031001  1DP</Item>
  </Header>
  <Ord xmlns="">
    <Count>000002</Count>
    <TagId>ORD</TagId>
    <Item> 0000031001  0001</Item>
  </Ord>
  <Ord xmlns="">
    <Count>000003</Count>
    <TagId>ORD</TagId>
    <Item> 0000031001  0001</Item>
  </Ord>
  <Ord xmlns="">
    <Count>000004</Count>
    <TagId>ORD</TagId>
    <Item> 0000031001  0001</Item>
  </Ord>
  <Ord xmlns="">
    <Count>000005</Count>
    <TagId>ORD</TagId>
    <Item> 0000031001  0001</Item>
  </Ord>
  <End xmlns="">
    <Count>000006</Count>
    <TagId>END</TagId>
  </End>
</Root>
```

Comment: Except that the file is a TAB delimited file, rather than a positional one.  So this won't work it this situation